# A Question in Layouts

Tags: java

I have a doubt in layouts.I have designed one layout using group layout using addgaps and groups.My Question is whether my design changes with screen size?That is I have designed layout for 15 inches monitor will the layout looks same in bigger size monitor screen?
Thank u
chaithu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you designed the layout. If you assign sizes and positions to components using pixels, then it won't scale. If you made good use of `preferredSize` and other properties designed to work with dynamic sizes, then it will scale.

Which did you do? You say you used group layouts, which means your screen will most likely scale. How well it scales is another question entirely.

Do you not have the opportunity to try the layout on a larger monitor to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the window smaller, does it update the layout to fit components? If yes, then most probably it will look fine on larger screen, if not... anyways, group layout is intended for GUI builders (like NetBeans). For handmade GUI, `Box` and `BorderLayout` will do the job most of the time.